# Rails logging to Apache logs rather than application log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I am running a Rails application on Apache using mod_passenger. I would like `Rails.logger` calls to write to the Apache error log rather than to the application's log file in `log/production.log`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Although this is not the answer to my question, I have decided to go a different way. One concern was that the Rails application `log/` log files would get too big. I am now using logrotate to address that concern. It does split the log messages between the Apache log and the Rails application log files, but I'll just have to live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config/environments/production.rb file you can add something like:

```
config.logger = Logger.new("/var/log/apache2/error.log")
```

Of course your app will need to have permissions to such a file. In addition intermixing Apache errors with your apps logs is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Wouldn't that override whatever Apache wrote?

Comment: Nice idea but it's likely to lead to interleaving in the error log. That is, because two processes are writing to the same file without mutual locking, their messages are likely to get mangled together.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly but I've just run a little test and `STDERR.puts "meep"` ended up in Apache's error log while using mod_passenger.

Perhaps then you could point `config.logger` at `STDERR`?